Reproducing photos from Glass negatives
I have been given a number of old (1960s) glass black-and-white negatives. I think they have been professionally taken. Is it possible to print them on my PC ?

You want to print them on your PC's case?

Are you sure that what you have are actually glass plates? Or are you perhaps misdating the plates? I would reckon that glass plates went out of use and were replaced by film about half a decade before the 1960s.

The most convenient way to reproduce the photos is by scanning them and then printing out the scanned images.  A quick google of "How to scan glass negatives" came up with this random blog as the first result How to Digitise Glass Plate Negatives
A few entries down the goole results also turned up this answer from a rather well known website: How best to digitally copy glass negatives?
I also saw various Youtube videos in the google results as well.  So there is a lot of practical information out there if you search for the correct terms.
Of course if you really want, you can do old school photo chemical printing.  This forum has some information on that: information on equipment to make prints from glass plate negs.

A collection of links without at least a summary of what the links say is discouraged here, mainly because the links will eventually be dead and then no one will know any more than when they started.

@MichaelC The context is there with pointing the OP at how to find the relevant information.  And if my second link is dead then we have more problems than just a dead link

Please see: How do I write a good answer?

You will need to have them scanned into a digital format (or do it yourself).
